# Postgresql + заполнение таблицы данными на основе уже существующих записей в этой же таблице

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица   **modes** в которой есть атрибуты
**link**, **name** , **antoherAtrr**.

**link**, **name** - строковые значения.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выполнить запрос всех имеющихся строк в таблице и умножить их на N-количество, и сделать вставку в эту же таблицу, но при этом, чтобы поля **link**, **name** - имели уникальное значение(например, добавить к существующим значениям в этих полях + рандомное число в виде строки).

```sql
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr)
                                 select * from modes
```

Данный код выдаст ошибку, так как нарушается уникальность первых 2-х столбцов.

У кого есть идеи как это написать ? Можете привести код с пояснениями ?

**Update.**

Вот что мне предложили сделать.

```sql
INSERT INTO modes (link, name)
SELECT mod.link || '_'||serial_sequence.range, mod.name || '_'||serial_sequence.range
FROM modes mod
         JOIN generate_series(1, 10) AS serial_sequence(range) ON true;
```

**(1, 10)** - это диапазон генерации. Здесь можно подставить любое количество записей, которое вы хотите увеличить. Я не совсем разобрался как он работает, иногда не срабатывал.

Решение рабочее ( **оно не мое**).

Answer (score 1):

Сделать можно вот так

```
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr)
select
    link||'_'||row_number() over (partition by link, name),
    name||'_'||row_number() over (partition by link, name),
    'text'
from modes
```

но я на 146% уверен, что ты неправильно решаешь *какую-то* задачу.

---

```
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr) values ('1', 'a', null);
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr) values ('1', 'b', null);
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr) values ('2', 'a', null);
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr) values ('2', 'b', null);

insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr)
select
    link||'_'||row_number() over (partition by link, name),
    name||'_'||row_number() over (partition by link, name),
    ids::text
from modes cross join (select 1 id union select 2 union select 3) ids

select * from modes
```

```
link    name    antoheratrr
1   a   
1   b   
2   a   
2   b   
1_1 a_1 (1)
1_2 a_2 (2)
1_3 a_3 (3)
1_1 b_1 (1)
1_2 b_2 (2)
1_3 b_3 (3)
2_1 a_1 (1)
2_2 a_2 (2)
2_3 a_3 (3)
2_1 b_1 (1)
2_2 b_2 (2)
2_3 b_3 (3)
```

Comment: в тестовом контуре мне нужно заполнить эту же таблицу и проверить производительность на 1000 записей. Все равно testcontainers очищаются

Comment: предоставленный код работает, но только для одной записи

Comment: работает прекрасно для многих записей

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1375718/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-pos/1375782#1375782