# Использование переменных, для хранения сгенерированных данных внутри функции Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

- таблица

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (

    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    data TIMESTAMP
);
```

- функция

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_table_foo()
    RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    id1 INT;
    name1 TEXT;
BEGIN

    id1 := generate_series(1, 1000000);
    name1:= md5(random()::text);

    INSERT INTO foo(id, name) values (id1, name1);

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

По задумке, данная функция должна используя переменные (именно переменные) получать от генераторов данные и затем полученные данные вставлять в соответствующие поля таблицы.

Я хотел бы заменить :

```sql
INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT i, md5(random()::text)
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;
```

При этом хотел бы "контролировать" (минимально) получение данных, сгенерированных во время работы функции. То есть хочется отделить код вставки данных и генерацию этих данных.
Возможно здесь нужен цикл.

Но на выходе **таблица пуста**, когда функцию пытаюсь запустить на выполнение (разумеется функция перед этим уже зарегистрирована в CУБД.)

Postgresql 13.3

Кто может быть знает как решить данную задачу ?

Comment: generate_series(1, 1000000) возвращает таблицу значений (миллион чисел), а не одно значение int, поэтому ее результат физически невозможно поместить в int. Эта функция должна завершаться ошибкой еще при компиляции, а может и при выполнении. Видимо вы ее пытаетесь выполнить в чем то, что не показывает ошибки. Если вам нужно одно значение для одной записи, то вероятно надо воспользоваться тем же random()

Comment: мне нужно заполнить именно таблицу сгенерированными записями

Comment: А почему вы хотите сделать это именно функцией с переменными, а не одним запросом insert/select ? Если действительно нужна функция и переменные, то обратите внимание, что insert при таком синтаксисе вставляет только одну запись и что бы создать много записей его надо выполнять многократно, а для этого в функции должен быть цикл, например по значениям получаемым из generate_series. Хотя проще сделать тогда id1=1 и в цикле прибавлять к нему по 1, пока не дойдем до миллиона

Comment: потому что хочу избежать сложного кода, то есть хочется четко видеть где данные получаются и как вставляются. и да согласен. здесь нужен цикл.

Comment: *есть хочется четко видеть где данные получаются и как вставляются* Это делается в виде CTE. Там чётко видно, откуда и как именно получаются значения, которые будут вставлены.

Comment: лучше привыкать к виду "сложного кода". это SQL, он заточен на работу с наборами данных. Функция с циклом будет в несколько раз медленнее

Comment: @skyho "при этом хотел бы "контролировать" (минимально) получение данных" - так параметры`generate_series` и позволяют контролировать сколько будет данных. Объяви их переменными и вызывай `INSERT INTO foo SELECT i, md5(random()::text) FROM generate_series(startId, endId) AS i;`

Comment: ну а мне это не подходит. мне не нравится такой подход. А функция с циклом для создания набора тестовых данных то что нужно и не важно сколько это времени занимает.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще решение, где primary key является UUID

```sql
create extension "pgcrypto";

create table user_type
(
    type_id varchar(32) not null
        primary key
);

insert into user_type
                    values ('GUEST'),
                           ('USER'),
                           ('CUSTOMER');

create table "user"
(
    id         varchar(38)             not null
        primary key
        constraint check_user_id
            check ((id)::text <> ''::text),
    type       varchar(32)             not null
        constraint fk_user_type
            references user_type,
    created_at timestamp default now() not null,
    updated_at timestamp default now() not null,
    enabled    boolean   default true
);
```

```sql
create unique index unq_idx_user_case_insensitive_id
    on "user" (lower(id::text));
```

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE genx(n, id) AS (
    VALUES (1, substr(gen_random_uuid()::text, 1, 29))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1, substr(gen_random_uuid()::text, 1, 29)
    FROM genx WHERE n < 30
)
insert into "user"
SELECT id,(array['GUEST', 'USER', 'CUSTOMER'])[floor(random() * 3 + 1)]  FROM genx;
```

теперь нужно создать таблицу и заполнить ее на основе данных выше созданной таблицы

```sql
create table user_details
(
    id           varchar(38)  not null
        primary key
        constraint fk_user_details_user_id
            references "user"
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    first_name   varchar(255) not null,
    email        varchar(255),
    mobile_phone varchar(15)  not null
        constraint unq_user_details_mobile_phone
            unique
        constraint check_user_details_mobile_phone
            check ((mobile_phone)::text <> ''::text),
    expired_at   timestamp
);
```

```sql
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        TABLE_RECORD RECORD;
        ID_USER      text;
        id_login_customer integer;
        id_custom BIGINT;
        PHONE text;
    BEGIN
        FOR TABLE_RECORD IN SELECT * FROM "public"."user" LIMIT 10   -- can select required fields only

            LOOP
                SELECT id
                INTO ID_USER
                FROM "public"."user" u
                WHERE u.id = TABLE_RECORD."id";
                RAISE NOTICE 'To print - ID_USER: %, TABLE_RECORD."id": % ', ID_USER, TABLE_RECORD."id";

                SELECT cd.mobile_phone INTO PHONE from user_details cd WHERE cd.id = TABLE_RECORD."id";

                id_custom := (SELECT floor(random() * (10000000000 - 1 + 1) + 1)::bigint);
                RAISE NOTICE 'Customer NEW: %', id_custom;

                id_login_customer := (select customer_id from customer_details cd where cd.customer_id = id_custom);

                BEGIN
                    while id_login_customer is not null
                        LOOP
                            id_login_customer := (
                                select customer_id 
                                from customer_details cd 
                                where cd.customer_id = id_custom);
                            id_custom := (SELECT floor(random() * (10000000000 - 1 + 1) + 1)::bigint);
                        end loop;
                    /*Команда RAISE NOTICE предназначена для вывода сообщений и вызова ошибок*/
                    RAISE NOTICE 'Customer EXISTS: %', id_login_customer;


                    RAISE NOTICE 'Customer NEW_IN_WHILE_CYCLE: %', id_custom;
                    id_login_customer := NULL;
                end;

                insert into customer_details (id,
                                              customer_id,
                                              first_name,
                                              email,
                                              mobile_phone)
                values (ID_USER,
                        id_custom,
                        'first_name-' || substr(gen_random_uuid()::text, 1, 10),
                        substr(gen_random_uuid()::text, 2, 7)
                            || '@' ||
                        substr(gen_random_uuid()::text, 2, 5)
                            || '.com',
                        PHONE
                        );

                id_custom := NULL;
            END LOOP;
    END
$$;
```

Answer (score -2):

### Решение

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_table_foo()
    RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE

    startId INT;
    endId INT;

    nameVar TEXT;
begin
    startId := 1;
    endId := 20;

    for idVar in startId..endId loop
            nameVar :=  md5(random()::text);
            insert into foo(id, name) values(idVar, nameVar);
        end loop;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: просьба оставлять комментарии . Уважайте других участников.